# Where do quants get historical FOMC meetings events for backtesting?

Tags: data, fomc

Is there any usual/best practice to fetch historical fomc meetings events online?

Comment: We tried to give you the best answer possible so it would be fair if you could upvote and accept - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can find information about the meetings online here:
http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm

As an example the following paper backtests certain effects supposedly connected with these meetings and whether they might be exploited:

[The Pre-FOMC Announcement Drift](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1923197)
 by David O. Lucca (Federal Reserve Banks - Federal Reserve Bank of New York) and Emanuel Moench (Deutsche Bundesbank), Journal of Finance, Forthcoming FRB of New York Staff Report No. 512, July 26, 2013

**Abstract**

> We document large average excess returns on U.S. equities in
>   anticipation of monetary policy decisions made at scheduled meetings
>   of the Federal Open Market Committee (FOMC) in the past few decades.
>   These pre-FOMC returns have increased over time and account for
>   sizable fractions of total annual realized stock returns. While other
>   major international equity indices experienced similar pre-FOMC
>   returns, we find no such effect in U.S. Treasury securities and
>   money market futures. Other major U.S. macroeconomic news
>   announcements also do not give rise to pre-announcement excess equity
>   returns. Pre-FOMC returns are higher in periods when the slope of the
>   Treasury yield curve is low, implied equity market volatility is high,
>   and when past pre-FOMC returns have been high. We discuss challenges
>   at explaining these returns with standard asset pricing theory.

The following chart is taken from the paper:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Fed website has all this information. The period 2010 to 2016 is very conveniently laid out here http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm [as already noted by vonjd], and meetings from earlier years can be looked up more laboriously here http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomc_historical.htm .

I made my own spreadsheet and I just update it once a year when the Fed posts new information.